# Loading model or collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm new to Backbone and I was using ExtJS before. My goal is to populate a Backbone collection with some data. Now... in ExtJS if I wanted to load a collection than I was using the .load() method that belonged to it. As I'm reading Backbone's documentation I can see that there are mostly feching / syncing methods assigned to 'models'. So my question is:

"If I want to load a Backbone's collection, should I load it directly or via 'model'?"

Comment: What's wrong with http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch ?

Comment: that's my question, should I use it and within this method access directly 'models' property or should I load models first inside of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Backbone Collection can be a collection of Backbone Models.
If you set your collection as:

```
YourCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: YourModel,
    url: '/url/to/json/collection';
    }
});
```

and your model as:

```
YourModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: '/url/to/json/model';
    }
});
```

Then you can do something like:

```
var collection = new YourCollection();
collection.fetch(); //GETs /url/to/json/collection
```

The path `/url/to/json/collection` should return a JSON array where each element in the array would be the JSON for your Models.

The path `/url/to/json/model` should return a JSON representing one Model.

Imagining your server returned JSON has a property like `"name"`, then you can do interesting stuff: `collection.where({name: 'some name'})`. This would return an array with `YourModel`s.

So, answering your initial question, yes you should load it via Backbone's collection.

Comment: Yes and that is what I'm dealing with... now my main concern is about the .fetch() method within collection. Should it load first YourModel and than YourModel should be pushed to YourCollection.models OR should I directly loaf YourCollection.models (and YourModel instances are unnecessary to the fetching process) ?

Comment: sorry I didn't see the last sentence, that is the answer that I needed.